# Clustering express node js app not working

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing, pm2

I have a simple express app with 2 endpoints code below

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("Hello")
})

app.get("/load", (req, res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) { }
    res.json("Load")
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at ${PORT}`)
})
```

I run it using pm2 start index.js -i 0

Which creates multiple instances for the app

Testing the endpoints side by side
I see "/" endpoint gets impacted with "/load" endpoint, which shouldn't be the case.